I converted my angular app into electron js app . How to send print on thermal printer with specific printer name from angular component
I faced problem to send a print from angular front end (web hosted) to locally connected printer without showing pop up of browser so i came to this solution that to convert my app in electron js and its finally done. if i want to send print from my angular component to locally connected thermal printer. How to solve this?
if someone already work on same issue please let me know if u have any reference doc then drop a link.
Many thanks
Nope!! not yet tried to solve it but I'm searching solution may be some of reference doc or any hint related to specific case.

Perhaps these articles will be helpful. Electron print without dialog (silent print), webContents.print() doesn't work under Windows when 'deviceName' is provided #17260, Silent printing not working in combination with deviceName (in v5.0.7 +) #19474
